# How to remove a views template file in theme folder?

Tags: 7, views

I put .tpl.php file inside my theme folder to override views output. Then I deleted this file because it was no use for me. And did "Rescan template files". Now it cannot find this file and gives errors on the page.

> File not found, in folder sites/all/themes/mytheme/templates/

I also cleared all my caches.

How can I remove this file for good?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my problem is related with APC or some sort of caching. After removing the file, I run

> $ httpd restart

from the command window on the server, then the errors are gone. Probably it cleared the APC cache.